# Is it possible to install Trac on diskstation 207+

Tags: trac, svn

I'm looking for a cheap personal project management and I have diskstation 207+. Is it possible to install trac witn svnserver on it?

cheers,

Perica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible:
http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_Subversion
and
http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=6454